# Пауза в работе сервера

Tags: php, email, sendmail, sleep

При рассылки писем:

```
mail($email, $subject, $final_message, $headers);
```

Есть ограничение на хостинге: "частота отправки писем не должна превышать 10 писем в минуту". 
Скажите какой функцией лучше воспользоваться для этого?
пробовал отправлять по 10 штук и использовать:

```
sleep(60);
```

Но проблема в том, что запрос отправляется Ajax - ом и после завершения желательно знать о выполнении команды. Но если количество писем 600-800 штук, то при работе команды sleep ответ по завершению с сервера может приходить часами. Посоветуйте, что делать? Спасибо.

Comment: мне кажется, в вопросе изложены несовместимые требования: *сразу* узнать о результате процесса, который может занять несколько *часов*. может быть, имеет смысл разделить процесс на стадии? отдельно *формирование рассылки* и отдельно *отправка* очередной порции писем.

Comment: Не совсем понял, поясните? Вы предлагаете это реализовать совместно с записьмо в БД, каким образом фиксировать? Не хотелось бы базу данных подключать на несколько часов. Было бы замечательно найти способ отправить запрос , получить ответ, что запрос поставлен в очередь и последним письмо отправить ответ администратору, мол "все готово"

Comment: да, база данных — вполне подходящее место для хранения *данных*. фиксировать факт отправки можно изменением соответствующего поля в таблице. «держать» базу не надо, достаточно периодически вызывать функцию, которая отправит очередную порцию писем и завершится. а когда очередь писем для отправки закончится — можно отправить отчёт администратору.

Comment: Архитектурно задачи должны быть разделены между бэкендом веб-приложения и почтовой системой. Первый передаёт письмо второй, получая лишь подтверждение, что письмо встало в очередь. Почтовая система по расписанию, с указанный максимальной скоростью берёт письма из очереди и отправляет их получателем. О факте успешной отправки можно узнать с помощью чисто почтового метода - DSN.